# Qual a função deste operador "=&" em PHP?

Tags: php, operadores

Se tenho o código abaixo:

```
$x = 1;
$y = 1;
if($x =& $y){
   echo "ok";
}else{
   echo "não";
}
```

Não importa que valor eu coloque no `$x` ou `$y`, sempre cai no `echo "ok"`. Agora se eu não definir uma das variáveis, cai no `echo "não"`:

```
$x = 1;
// $y = 1;
if($x =& $y){
   echo "ok";
}else{
   echo "não";
}
```

O que esse operador `=&` verifica entre os dois operandos?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ele sempre irá cair no `echo "ok"` pois isto `=&` não é um operador de **comparação** e sim uma **atribuição por referência**.

Este operador irá realmente ligar as duas variáveis por referência, ou seja, ao modificar o valor de uma, será modificado o valor da outra, após esta atribuição. Verifique abaixo no exemplo:

```
$x = 1;
$y =& $x;
echo $x; // 1
echo $y; // 1
$x = 2;
echo $x; // 2
echo $y; // 2
```

Answer (score 4):

O `$x &= $y` faz o  `$x` e `$y` apontem para o mesmo local, como é dito no manual, http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.references.whatdo.php.

---

O `if` não tem nada haver com isso, o `if` está sendo executado porque o valor de  `$y` é diferente de 0. Mas, isso ocorre com qualquer operação de atribuição, como `if($x = 1){}`.

Quando você faz:

```
// $y = 1;
if($x =& $y){
}
```

Não há nenhum valor para `$y`, por consequência ele é *nulo/0/false* e então não atende o `if`. Quando você define qualquer valor diferente de `0` no `$y` o `if` será atendido normalmente, assim é atendido usando `$x = $y`.